# Arranging rows of a matrix for maximum distance

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, distance

I have two identical matrices of 7 cols x 128 rows with each element containing one of two values (either 0.1 or 0.3).  The matrices are a representation of all the possible permutations of the two values (0.1 and 0.3) within 7 variables (columns). An excerpt of the matrices is shown below and you can see how the possible permutations progress from 7x values of "0.1" to 7x values of "0.3" with every possible permutation in-between.  There are 128 rows because the possible permutations are 2^7 = 128.

Question.  I would like to be able to rearrange the rows (whole rows) in one of the matrices to maximise the mathematical (or Euclidean) distance between the rows. So for example, row 128 of matrix 2 is as far away as possible (within this set) from row 1 of matrix 1 but there will be rows in the middle of the two sets (matrices) that are close together.  Is there a way of finding the optimal arrangement of rows to maximise the distance?

I understand that the matrix of distances between elements of two matrices is known as the distance matrix and so I guess that I am asking that I would like to be able to arrange the whole rows of one matrix to maximise the distance matrix between the two matrices.

I have looked at calculating the possible permutations of 128 rows and running an apply function but there are 3.856204823 E+215 permutations of 128 row numbers and the vector is bigger than my 128GB RAM.

I would like this to go beyond 2x matrices to n x matrices but at this point I would be happy with a 2x matrix solution.  One step at a time!

Any thoughts or suggestions would be very much appreciated  Thank you.

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7
1    0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
2    0.3  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
3    0.1  0.3  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
4    0.3  0.3  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
5    0.1  0.1  0.3  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
.
.
.
125  0.1  0.1  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3
126  0.3  0.1  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3
127  0.1  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3
128  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3
```

The matrices were made using the following code:

```
cor.vec=c(0.1,0.3)
x.lst = list()
for (i in 1:2)
  {
  x = expand.grid(rep(list(1:length(cor.vec)), 7))
  x[x == 1] = cor.vec[1]
  x[x == 2] = cor.vec[2]
  x.lst[[i]] = x
}
```

Comment: Surely the greatest distance matrix will be `mat2 = 0.4 - mat1` - i.e. where each element has the opposite value (0.1 or 0.3) from the first matrix???

Comment: `the vector is bigger than my 128GB RAM` made me laugh :D

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It's asking for something that is impossible. If the OP wants to propose a method that involves something to do with sampling or approximate methods he should research what is known and define a method to be implemented.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Gustar, this approach provides me with a quick way to reverse order the rows of second matrix and produces the largest possible distance for the first and last rows but minimum distance for those rows in the middle that are similar. This is not a solution but has helped so thank you. I feel that there must be a way to organise the rows to achieve the largest average geometric distance.   It may be difficult but not impossible. 
 Thank you.

Comment: Also rather than calculating the distance between rows - maybe there is a way of identifying the most dissimilar rows and matching these or producing a vector of row numbers that can be used to order the second matrix?  I feel that this may be something that can be done with a join or such like but I´m not so experienced with these functions.

Comment: @Dan Why do you think the distance is less for the rows in the middle? Every pair of rows has the same distance (plus or minus 0.2 for all seven elements), so the Euclidean distance will always be the same (about 0.53).

Comment: @Andrew Gustar.  Thank Andrew, I´ll take a look at it.

Comment: @Andrew Gustar.  Thanks you are correct.  This solution provides a second matrix with the largest possible distances constructed from the possible values provided.  Thank you.  One question:  Can I assume that the 0.4 constant is simply an addition of the possible values and would also work if the possible values also included negative numbers or the constant total was over 1.0.

Comment: @Dan Yes, if you only have two values, A and B, then you just need to subtract one of them from (A+B) to get the other one.

Comment: @ Andrew Gustar Thank you!  Can I please ask what I would do if I have more than two variables?  i.e. A, B and C. Thanks.